# Does query by id faster then other queries in SOLR (Lucene)?

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, full-text-search

Id is a primary key, another_field is a some string field.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=id:c2c32773-1691-11df-97a5-7038c432aabf
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=another_field:c2c32773-1691-11df-97a5-7038c432aabf
```

Is the first query faster?

Answer (score 0):

Query on id does not make it faster then any other query unless the fields are text fields which would take it a bit longer depending upon the analysis performed.
Also if you want to query on Id or fixed valued fields better using the Filter Query which would be much more faster cause of the field caching.